# Bifurcate flow on Mule

Tags: mule

It's possible to bifurcate the payload to send the same payload to two different connectors?I want to send the same payload to a database conector and a smpt connector ,I have to use 2 flows or I can send the same  payload in only one flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a use case for [Scatter-Gather](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Scatter-Gather). This will send a copy of the payload to several targets and then collect the answers.

Comment: Scatter Gather is nice when you have to do something with the results of both connector calls.  If either one can be fire-and-forget, a simple <async> will do well

Answer (score 0):

I'll follow afelisatti suggestion, just bear in mind that scatter-gather will, by default, wait for all routes to complete before continue. This may not be what you want.